# Transfering data from one view to another

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core

I have model "Test", on the first view user enters "Title", "CountOfWords", "Level". Depending on the value of the CountOfWords field, I generate the input fields in the second view and fill the Words list with them, and I want to display all this general data in the third view. How can I pass first three first fields to second view and then these three fields together with Words list to third view?

My model "Test":

```
public class Test
{
    [Required]
    public string Title { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Level { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public int CountOfWords { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }

    public List<Word> Words { get; set; }
    public CreateModel()
    {
        Date = DateTime.Now;
        Words = new List<Word>();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could create a separated model for each step, with its own validations and use `Session` to store the steps.

```
public class ModelStep1
{
    ... properties
}
public class ModelStep2
{
    ... properties
}
```

In the controller:

```
public ActionResult SubmittedStep1(ModelStep1 model)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        Session["Step1Data"] = model;
        return View("Step2View", CreateModelForStep2());        
    }
    else 
    {
        return View(model);
    }
}
```